# Fitting fancyhdr's chead in a colorbox

Tags: header-footer, boxes, fancyhdr

I am trying to create a header using `fancyhdr` in which the `rhead` and `lhead` parts are two images, of the same and known size.

In the center, I would like to put some text (perhaps the document's title), but when it is too long, it does not fit in the header:

[image: output]

How could I force that line to break and fit in the colorbox? Should I use any other approach instead?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn]{article}

% Packages needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\definecolor{ctagblue}{HTML}{003366}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}
\chead{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\colorbox{ctagblue}{\makebox[10cm][c]{\vrule height 1cm depth 1cm width 0pt \textcolor{white}{\bfseries loasdf sdofkjaosdjgas jkgaslk gjlsjasdlgk jasg alksdfj sdklfj alkdfj laskdfjasdf}}}}}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The logo image has been taken from [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Wikimedia-logo.png).

### EDIT 1

I would like to keep the box with a fixed dimension as shown in the image, so the height should be constant even when the text has one or multiple lines.

### EDIT 2

Would it be possible to fit the text in the box even when it is very long? That would mean to automatically scale the font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the package `tcolorbox`, which will allow **any** text to properly fit in the box (no matters its length):

```
% [...]
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
% [...]
\chead{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=ctagblue,colframe=black,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=ctagblue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
% [...]
```

If it is possible, the `basedim` text size will be used for the text to fit in the box:

[image]

Otherwise, when the text is too long to fit in the box with `basedim` size, it is automatically resized (reduced):

[image]

This may be the best solution for a document template, as you never know which text will be placed there in the future, nor its length.

See complete code here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn]{article}

% Packages needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\definecolor{ctagblue}{HTML}{003366}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}
\chead{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=ctagblue,colframe=black,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=ctagblue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, using the natural height of the `\parbox`, no `\makebox`used in  `\chead` (and simpler code!). I also suggest the text in the header be in sans serif, to match the style of the logo (this may depeng on the real logo, of course). And the logo is rather large for a header, I suggest to let it partially flow into the margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% Packages needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\definecolor{ctagblue}{HTML}{003366}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}}}%
\chead{ \colorbox{ctagblue}{\parbox[b][][c]{10cm}{\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries loasdf sdofkjaosdjgas jkgaslk gjlsjasdlgk jasg alksdfj sdklfj alkdfj laskdfjasdf}}}}
\rhead{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the same height for the logo and the centre part of the header, replace the code for the header with this one (for a real height of 2cm, I need a parbox of 1.8 cm — I don't know why):

```
\lhead{\raisebox{-1mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}}}%
\chead{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt} \colorbox{ctagblue}{\parbox[b][1.8cm][c]{10cm}{\centering\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries loasdf sdofkjaosdjgas jkgaslk gjlsjasdlgk jasg alksdfj sdklfj alkdfj laskdfjasdf}}}
\rhead{\raisebox{-1mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Wikimedia-logo}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like the box to have the same height as the images, though. (I will update the question).

Comment: @Peque: OK, I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need fewer boxes ;).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Packages needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ctagblue}{HTML}{003366}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}}
\chead{\colorbox{ctagblue}{%
    \parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{%
      \centering
      \textcolor{white}{\bfseries loasdf sdofkjaosdjgas jkgaslk gjlsjasdlgk jasg alksdfj sdklfj alkdfj laskdfjasdf}%
    }%
  }%
}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that I've used the tiger image because it is part of a standard TeX distribution. Also, `10pt` and `onecolumn` are default for `article`.

[image: tiger header]

To 'flip' the tiger in accordance with Bernard's suggestion, you can use `\reflectbox{}`. For example:

```
\rhead{\reflectbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}}}
```

if you would like to protect the header from harm:

[image: tigers on watch]

or

```
\lhead{\reflectbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}}}
```

if your text is otherwise liable to escape:

[image: tigers on guard]

Comment: May I suggest to flip the left tiger?

Comment: @Bernard That's a good idea (which occurred to me, too) but I was only using the tiger as a place-holder because I was too lazy to download the wikimedia logo!

Comment: +1. Great solution and thanks for the comments and suggestions too! I will wait before accepting the answer and see if my answer may also be interesting for others, as it allows for automatically resizing of the text inside the box. Comments/improvements on my solution are very welcome. :-)

Comment: @cfr: It was only a suggestion so the text in the header can't escape. Or add bars to the `\parjail`.

Comment: @Bernard See my edit. I initially assumed you meant flip the right tiger as that's what had occurred to me. Then I reread your comment so I flipped the left one instead...

Comment: @Peque Certainly if the header will change, but possibly even if it will not, automatically scaling text to fit may lead to unwanted effects. For example, you do not want the text in the heading on different pages to be in different font sizes. Even if the heading is the same throughout the document or only used on one page, think about whether the text should match the size of something else. You may not want it to be a little larger than something, for example, but either the same size or clearly bigger or smaller. You want font sizes to look consistent and to complement each other.

Comment: @cfr: No, no, the tigers must *watch* the header text…

Comment: @Bernard Doesn't the last pair do that? Or are you worried there is other unwatched text in my post?

Comment: @cfr: It's the other pair that seem to be looking elsewhere. I'm sure they're accomplices. Look like they turn their heads while whistling. Comment apart, did you notice tigers wear *bars*?

Comment: @cfr: the header will not change in single document, but it will change between documents. The idea is to create a template in which the text displayed in the header is the title of the document. Notice how my solution uses a fixed size for all titles unless it is impossible to fit in the box, only in that case, the text size will be reduce.

Comment: @Bernard ??????

Answer (score 1):

You could set the entire heading using `\chead` and arrange things inside a `tabular` for better management of widths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{ctagblue}{HTML}{003366}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\chead{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}p{5pt}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm-10pt}p{5pt}m{2cm}}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2\baselineskip,valign=c]{example-image-a} &
    \cellcolor{ctagblue} &
    \cellcolor{ctagblue}\textcolor{white}{\bfseries loasdf sdofkjaosdjgas jkgaslk gjlsjasdlgk jasg alksdfj sdklfj alkdfj laskdfjasdf} &
    \cellcolor{ctagblue}&
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2\baselineskip,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Some considerations regarding the above code:

- [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) (with the `[export]` option) loads [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and allows for centering content vertically (via `valign=c`).
- [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) provides an `m{<len>}` column for vertical anchoring of cells.
- Two additional (empty) columns were created to create a `\tabcolsep`-like gap between the images and the paragraph text.